# How do I display the input of the user, if the user guesses correctly in hangman c#

Tags: c#, for-loop, foreach

I am trying to make a version of hangman in c# using the console application.

Right now what is working is for every letter that the user has not guessed it displays an * but what is not working is when the user guesses correctly it doesn't show the letter that the user inputted on the next turn.

Here is the code that I have that displays and shows of the user guessed any of the letters.

```
 static void PlayHangMan(string randomWord)
    {
        char[] charArray;
        char userGuess;
        int counter = 0;

        charArray = randomWord.ToCharArray();

        while (counter < charArray.Length)
        {
            Console.Write("(Guess) Enter a letter in a word ");
            foreach (char character in charArray)
            {
                Console.Write("*");
            }
            Console.Write(" > ");
            userGuess = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar;
            Console.WriteLine();
            for (int index = 0; index < charArray.Length; index++)
            {
                if (charArray[index] == userGuess)
                {
                    charArray[index] = userGuess;
                    Console.Write(charArray[index]);
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.Write("*");
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
            counter++;
        }
    }
```

---UPDATE---

I have been able to get the input to display correctly now thanks to the suggestions down below. But now I am trying to keep track of when the user guesses incorrectly. I have tried what is below. But I am getting very wired numbers. Like if I only guess wrong once I would want the guesses number to increase by one only , instead it is display 70 instead of one. Not too sure why

```
 while (found.Any(c => c == '*'))
        {
            Console.Write("(Guess) Enter a letter in a word ");
            Console.Write(found);
            Console.Write(" > ");
            userGuess = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar;
            Console.WriteLine();

            for (int index = 0; index < charArray.Length; index++)
            {
                if (charArray[index] == userGuess && userGuess != lettersUsed[index])
                {
                    found[index] = userGuess;
                    lettersUsed[index] = userGuess;
                }
                else if (lettersUsed[index] == userGuess)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"{userGuess} is already in the word");
                }
                else if (charArray[index] != userGuess && userGuess != lettersUsed[index])
                {
                    guesses++;
                }
            }
        }
```

Thanks for the suggestions!

Comment: +1 for creativity and ingenuity! And for providing code we can reproduce. I'm playing hangman. Be back in a few.

Comment: The problem is that you need to keep track of all the letters that have every been guessed and use that to determine if you should print the letter or the star.  Also the `while` loop should stop either when all the letters are guessed (not the same as the counter reaching the length) or when you get to a maximum allowed number of guesses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve it by introducing an additional array with found symbols, something like in code below. The solution is pretty simple and straightforward, `test` word is used as an example

```cs
int counter = 0;

var charArray = "test".ToCharArray();
var found = new char[charArray.Length];
for (int i = 0; i < charArray.Length; i++)
{
    found[i] = '*';
}

while (counter < charArray.Length)
{
    Console.Write("(Guess) Enter a letter in a word ");
    foreach (char character in charArray)
    {
        Console.Write("*");
    }

    Console.Write(" > ");
    var userGuess = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar;
    Console.WriteLine();
    for (int index = 0; index < charArray.Length; index++)
    {
        if (charArray[index] == userGuess)
        {
            found[index] = userGuess;
        }
        Console.Write(found[index]);
    }

    var any = false;
    foreach (var c in found)
        if (c == '*')
            any = true;

    if (!any)
        break;


    Console.WriteLine();
    counter++;
}
```

Example output

[image]

Comment: better and simpler than what I was going to suggest. +1

Comment: Thanks! It worked. Would anybody have any suggestions on how I would go about ending the program when the user guesses the word correctly before reaching the length of the word? Thanks

Comment: @Cole.C you can check how many `*` symbols are remaining in `found` array. If this equals zero, you should stop

Comment: @Cole.C `if (!found.Any(c => c == '*')) break;` the simplest solution using `System.Linq`, I'll update an answer

Comment: @Cole.C Please, have a look at updated answer, I've added a check when user guesses the word, solution with `Linq` is also possible

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski I have tried what is in the suggested answer, but I am not able to get it to work. Even when the entire word is guessed its still allowing me to enter a guess. I tired putting the second `if`statement in and out of the `foreach`loop but had no luck. I know that using `Linq` would be easier but I would like to know a method on how not to use that.

Comment: @Cole.C Please, have a look at updated answer. You should this code inside `while` loop before increasing a counter ```var any = false;
    foreach (var c in found)
        if (c == '*')
            any = true;

    if (!any)
        break;``` it'll break the main loop when there are no more `*` symbols in `found` array

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski Ahh okay I was able to get it to work. I am trying now to keep track of when the user guesses wrong in the main `for` loop I tried adding `if (userGuess != charArray[index] gusses++` But I am getting wried numbers like 70 and 120. I am unsure how why I am getting these kind of numbers. Would you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

> "Would anybody have any suggestions on how I would go about ending the
>   program when the user guesses the word correctly before reaching the
>   length of the word?"

I took some other liberties as well.

```
        static void PlayHangMan(string wordToGuess, int numberOfGuesses)
        {
            try
            {
                int counter = 0;
                bool victory = false;

                var charArray = wordToGuess.ToCharArray();
                var found = new char[charArray.Length];
                for (int i = 0; i < charArray.Length; i++)
                {
                    found[i] = '*';
                }

                string hiddenWord = string.Empty;
                foreach (char character in charArray)
                {
                    hiddenWord = hiddenWord + "*";
                }

                while (counter < numberOfGuesses)
                {
                    Console.Write($"(Guess left: {numberOfGuesses - counter}) Enter a letter in a word: {hiddenWord} > ");

                    // Wait for user input
                    var userGuess = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar;

                    hiddenWord = string.Empty;
                    Console.WriteLine();
                    for (int index = 0; index < charArray.Length; index++)
                    {
                        if (charArray[index] == userGuess)
                        {
                            found[index] = userGuess;
                            hiddenWord = hiddenWord + userGuess;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            hiddenWord = hiddenWord + found[index];
                        }
                    }
                    counter++;
                    if (!found.Any(f => f == '*'))
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"You won! Word: {hiddenWord}");
                        victory = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (!victory)
                    Console.WriteLine("You are out of guesses.");

                Console.Read();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                var m = ex.Message;
            }
        }
```

[image]

or

[image]